# Need a better way to programmatically clear and set user settings in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I'm writing a vscode profile management extension to both profile user settings as well as the installed extensions, but have hit a bit of a roadblock.

For my extension, I need to clear out the currently set settings in the user's settings.json file, but as far as my knowledge goes there is no way through the extension API to get an exact representation of the keys in the settings.json file, which is needed to delete the settings with the `WorkspaceConfiguration.update("key", undefinded, ConfigurationTarget.Global)` function. So for that I wrote this function:

```js
/**
 * Clears out the Global (user) settings.json of all values.
 */
public async clearGlobalConfig() {
    // Due to limitations on updating configuration values, all possible
    // paths must be attempted for an update, from most specific to least
    const fullConfigPaths = mapObjectPaths(this.getGlobalConfig());
    // WorkspaceConfig object for doing config update operations
    const workspaceConfig = workspace.getConfiguration();

    // Iterate over all possible config paths
    for (const key of fullConfigPaths) {
        // Attempt to unset the value (will not unset till it matches the
        // exact path as it matches in the settings.json file)
        await workspaceConfig.update(key, undefined, ConfigurationTarget.Global);
    }
}
```

However it takes about 10 - 20 seconds to run, at-least with my current settings, and the window flashes each time a setting is removed.

The next issue is grabbing the settings from the settings.json to save inside of a profile config. When you do a `workspace.getConfguration().inspect("")?.globalValue`, the object that is returned is not a 1:1 with the settings.json, all of the dot notated keys are removed and the object is unflattened. Which is bad because now, again, I don't know the proper keys that need to be used with `WorkspaceConfiguration.update()` to set the setting when a profile is loaded.

So I wrote this function to attempt to probe the returned object from the `workspace.getConfiguration()...` call to get a 1:1 representation of the settings.json file to save in a profile config:

```js
/**
 * Attempts to get an object that matches the contents of the user's
 * settings.json file exactly.
 * 
 * @returns An object that should match the contents of the user 
 * settings.json
 */
public async getGlobalSettingsFileContents(): Promise<Dictionary> {
    // Get the current user settings (minus this extension's settings)
    const runningConfig = this.getGlobalConfig();
    // Get all the possible full dot notated paths in the config object (from
    // most specific to least specific)
    const configPaths = mapObjectPaths(runningConfig);

    // Grab the WorkSpaceConfiguration object update function for reuse
    const updateFunction = workspace.getConfiguration().update;

    // The settings object with the proper settings.json keys to store in the
    // profile
    let actualSettings: Dictionary = {};

    // Previously checked config object path
    let previousPath = "";

    // Iterate over all the possible configuration object's dot paths
    for (const configPath of configPaths) {
        // If the previous path was a valid settings key AND the current path
        // is just a less specific object path
        if (has(actualSettings, previousPath) && startsWith(previousPath, configPath)) {
        continue;
        }

        // Get the current value before testing
        const currentValue = get(runningConfig, configPath);

        // Attempt to see if unsetting the settings value at this object path
        // works
        await updateFunction(configPath, undefined, ConfigurationTarget.Global);

        // Get the new value after the attempted unset
        const newValue = get(this.getGlobalConfig(), configPath);

        // If the value has changed (newValue probably being undefined)
        if (!isEqual(currentValue, newValue)) {
        // Then this was a valid settings key, save it
        actualSettings[configPath] = currentValue;
        }

        // Save path for checking against the next path
        previousPath = configPath;
    }


    // Get the actual settings keys that were just probed
    const actualConfigKeys = keys(actualSettings);

    // Iterate over the settings keys
    for (const configKey of actualConfigKeys) {
        // Attempt to re-add all the settings that were removed in the probing
        // process
        // WILL FAIL IF THERE ISN'T AN EXTENSION THAT CORRESPONDS TO THE SETTING
        await updateFunction(configKey, actualSettings[configKey], ConfigurationTarget.Global);
    }

    // Return what should be in the actual settings.json file
    return actualSettings;
}
```

But the issue now is, after removing the settings and then trying to re-add them at the exact key they were removed from, if the corresponding extension was not installed, it will throw an error:
[image]

So now my question is, is there a better way of programmatically editing the user settings.json, preferably within the vscode API and without needing to directly do filesystem operations?

Link to the project: https://github.com/SLGShark6/vscode-profile-manager/tree/development

Comment: The API you use seems to be slow as each small change you make triggers the underly configuration system to remap. It should be quicker if you modify the JSON file directly.

Comment: I suggest using the `jsonc-parser` plugin to parse the `settings.json`.  It was written by a vscode team member and is used extensively within vscode.  `  const rootNode = jsonc.parseTree(document.getText()); ` returns an array of nodes, in this case separate settings.  Replace `document.getText()` with the text of the settings file or any json file.

Comment: The only issue I'm having with accessing the settings.json file directly, is consistently finding it across different setups, such as codespaces, remote-container, and vscode portable, plus I'm not sure if platforms (windows, mac, linux) would play into this any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little cheesy, but I found a safe enough work around for editing the settings.json file within the vscode ecosystem.

(note: the `Dictionary` type is just a type I defined myself, it's equal for the most part to `object`)

```js
import * as JSONC from 'jsonc-parser';
import {
   commands,
   window,
   Range,
   Position
} from 'vscode';

/**
 * Gets the settings object directly from the settings.json file.
 * 
 * @returns Parsed object from the user settings.json file
 */
async function getSettingsJSON(): Promise<Dictionary> {
    // Open the user settings.json file in a new editor
    await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openSettingsJson");

    // Grab the new active editor from the window (should be the one we just
    // opened)
    const activeEditor = window.activeTextEditor!;
    // Get the open document from the active editor (should be the
    // settings.json file)
    const settingsDocument = activeEditor.document;

    // Get all of the text contained in the file
    const documentText = settingsDocument.getText();

    // Close the active settings.json editor
    await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");

    // Return the document parsed to a proper object
    return JSONC.parse(documentText);
}

/**
 * Writes a passed settings object directly to the user settings.json file,
 * overwriting the contents.
 * 
 * @param settings Settings object to overwrite the settings.json file with
 */
async function setSettingsJSON(settings: Dictionary) {
    // Open the user settings.json file in a new editor
    await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openSettingsJson");

    // Grab the new active editor from the window (should be the one we just
    // opened)
    const activeEditor = window.activeTextEditor!;
    // Get the open document from the active editor (should be the
    // settings.json file)
    const settingsDocument = activeEditor.document;

    // Open an edit operation to update the settings document
    activeEditor.edit((editBuilder) => {
        // Make a range from start to end of the document
        const startPosition = new Position(0,0);
        const endPosition = settingsDocument.lineAt(settingsDocument.lineCount - 1).rangeIncludingLineBreak.end;
        const range = new Range(startPosition, endPosition);

        // Replace everything with the new settings object
        editBuilder.replace(range, JSON.stringify(settings));
    });

    // Save the changed settings.json file
    await settingsDocument.save();
    // Close the active settings.json editor
    await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");
}
```